# require в node.js

Tags: node.js, requirejs

У меня есть папка, к примеру `functions` и мне нужно взять из нее файл `main.js`.
как это сделать я уже знаю

```
var main = require("./functions/main");
```

Но есть такая ситуация в это папке больше файлов и каждый раз мне надо будет "рекуайрить" разные. Вот это пример как я представляю

```
var file = main2;
var main = require("./functions/").require(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var file = "main2";
var main = require("./functions/" + file);
```

Comment: извините что засоряю stachoverflow, что то не выспался =)